# Ensure at compile time that PackageReference of my Project is not required for consumers of my Project

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I want to ensure at compile time that a PackageReference of my Project is not required for consumers of my Project.

**Example**

Project.csproj contains this PackageReference:

`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.3" PrivateAssets="All" />`

This means that Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore will not flow to the consumers of Project.

However, if I expose a public method in Project with a signature containing a type from Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, the consumer will have to install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore in their project as well. An example could be the following method in a public class in Project:

`public DbSet<Blog> GetDbEntries()`

I want to instruct the compiler to forbid such type-bleeding to consumers, is that possible?

Comment: Pretty sure it's a no. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: To ensure that dependencies are properly encapsulated in my Project, so that when I ship it as a NuGet package, the consumers do not have to install other NuGet packages.

Comment: You can disable `compile` information flowing to your consumers by specifying PrivateAssets="contentfiles;analyzers;build;compile". 

Note that because you have a runtime dependency on that package, your consumers will have to install it, but you can prevent it from bleeding into their intellisense.

Comment: Note that the value is appropriated from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#controlling-dependency-assets